# Insert layout into other layout's child

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I'm trying to set a layout which consists on 2 borders, one on the left, and other on the right. This layout will be in all the activities of my app.

The thing would be, set this layout as root, and get the rest of the layouts fitted on the space between these 2 border's layout.

**These are the conditions:**

- menu_layout.xml gets inflated by its on class Menu_view.java which extends RelativeLayout.
- The rest of the layout's must get fitted inside the menu_layout.xml
- must to say that menu_layout.xml which as said consist on 2 borders, these borders contains icons to access other activities, so it's class Menu_view.java contains the onClickListeners and this is way the layout is inflated.

**What I need to achieve:**

- As I said, I need to set this menu layout as root and get the rest of layouts fitted in the space inside of it.

**What I've tried:**

- I've tried including the menu_layout.xml in other layouts as a parent view, but part of these layout's get covered by the borders of the layout.
- I've tried inflating this layout programmatically but also seems I can't call a layout's resource that doesn't belong to the activity.

So, what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: If your borders are in a background image, you can make this background a 9patch and set a padding to it(bottom et right side of the 9patch), would be a solution i guess.

Comment: I've tried this way, but i'm looking for something more specific... something like having a linearlayout inside the menus and setting this space as where other activities must go... but I'm not able to do it